# iOS App Crashes with Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, crash, distribution

I recently submitted an update to my app to the AppStore. It was quickly approved and released. I updated the app on my own device, I see the loading screen... and then it crashes. It crashes, without fail, every time I launch it.

I ran the app on my device from Xcode in the exact form that was submitted to the AppStore and the same thing happened. Xcode comes up with this message:

> Failed to get task for process XXXX.

This means there is some kind of **distribution certificate issue**. Now, I know that an app signed with a distribution certificate *cannot* be run on development device from Xcode for testing. When I test the app on my device with a **development or Ad-Hoc profile, it runs fine**.

Why would my distribution certificate fail to work even from the AppStore approved version of my app?
And a somewhat more unsettling question: how did this issue get past **both** Application Loader / iTC Validation **AND** the Apple Review board?

I have recreated my app distribution certificate and reloaded it into Xcode. I archived it and validated it, hoping I would get some feedback, but it passed validation.

**How can I be sure my distribution certificate will work when I submit to the AppStore? Why didn't it work the first time?**

Here's a link to a crash log that I received (I didn't paste it here b/c its too long): http://pastie.org/private/n19fejrdhcmm3hi2jzzf8a

**Edit**: CleverError [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/23315317?noredirect=1) that the crash may be due to an issue with my XCDataModel. Is there anyway I can restore a clean XCDataModel that isn't corrupted or deleted?

Comment: Try deleting the app from your device before installing the app store version. It looks like its crashing when setting up core data which is most likely caused by having having made changes to the xcdatamodel file.

Comment: @CleverError Ohhh that makes sense! I removed the xcdatamodel file (oops) b/c I didn't use core data directly. Is there any way to restore that file?

Comment: Not unless your using version control for your project.

Comment: @CleverError Turns out the core data setup in the AppDelegate was old outdated code leftover from when I created the app for iOS 4, I just got rid of it and eliminated the issue altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distribution profile is not used during development for testing app in device(For this you should use development profile) thats why app terminates after first launch. If you need to install app in device using distribution profile then you should generate **IPA** and then install that IPA in your device.

And there will be no problem in apple store submission of your app if your IPA installs fine in your device and app don't crash.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have know that testing with a distribution profile doesn't work... As I stated in the question: `When I test the app on my device with a development or Ad-Hoc profile, it runs fine.`

Comment: I am using `development profile` but my app is still crashing!